# Horizontally scroll-able cards in ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

I am using ionic 4 and I want to get the result like shown in this image:

[image]

Comment: image1 is a link click  on this i want that   kind of results

Answer (score 19):

You might want to explore [ion-slides](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides) as basis for such cards scrolling:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>
            Ionic 4 template
        </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-slides [options]="{ slidesPerView: 'auto', zoom: false, grabCursor: true }">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let card of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]" style="width: 150px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid #f8f8f8">
      <ion-col>
        <ion-label>Card #{{ card }}</ion-label>
        <ion-img style="pointer-events:none" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></ion-img>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

Editable demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-oapfyt

Comment: there  is one more issue space between the cards are not customized?is there any solution? @Sergey

Comment: you can totally control the space via css or via options config. What space issue do you have? can you share exact parameters or requirements?

Comment: using Ionic 5 here and this works like a charm, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Great answer by Sergey, but after ionic v6 `ion-slides` will be deprecated in favor to [Swiper.js](https://ionicframework.com/docs/vue/slides).

Here is an example of how slides look now and [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ionic-6-vue-3-forked-rcbifc?file=/src/components/Swiper.vue):

```
<template>
  <ion-app>
    <ion-content class="ion-padding">
          <h1>Main Content</h1>
          <swiper :height="200" :slides-per-view="3" :spaceBetween="10">
            <swiper-slide
              v-for="swiper in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]"
              :key="swiper"
              style="background-color: green; height: 50px">
              {{ swiper }}
            </swiper-slide>
          </swiper>
        </ion-content>
  </ion-app>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

[i want this kind of results.as shown in image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TjLb.png)