# How can i make horizontal scrolling cards?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to make horizontal scrolling cards on the home page of my ionic angular app but it seems like the method is changing with each version of ionic.

[Horizontally scroll-able cards in ionic 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59361951/horizontally-scroll-able-cards-in-ionic-4)

I tried the way mentioned below but it fails to compile.

`

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>
            Ionic 4 template
        </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-slides [options]="{ slidesPerView: 'auto', zoom: false, grabCursor: true }">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let card of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]" style="width: 150px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid #f8f8f8">
      <ion-col>
        <ion-label>Card #{{ card }}</ion-label>
        <ion-img style="pointer-events:none" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></ion-img>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Regardless of how you go about using ion-slider here, take not that ion-slider was deprecated with later versions of Ionic and finally obsolete with Ionic 7, so better check out swiper.js that Ionic now supports.